# Working in a website making an OLX like selling platform, which plugin should i use?

Tags: wordpress

i'm working in a website that i need to make the user make login, complete a form and the forms comes to me as an POST(it`s a OLX like platform). i used WPforms basic but the form is only a form, to make it a post i need to pay. i already tried using User Submitted Posts but i cant customize the labels and to do that is paid as well. do i have any chances to make the post with custom labels and form or i will really have to pay for it ?

i already use like 2 or 3 plugin and nothing, i'm new in the WordPress universe so any tip will be very helpfull. i just want to make the user fill the data and that i can make the post later or it will be posted automatically

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.